# Can Rsyslog process messages before saving them?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

The messages that I'm sending to syslog have some tags like so:

```
"[date] [text here] tags:tag1,tag2,tag3 [more text here]"
```

I already have a rule that only saves lines that contain the text "tags:" to a specific file.

It would be great if that file only contained a substring of that message, in this case just the date and the tags part.

Can rsyslog do some processing/manipulation to a message prior to saving it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. The place to look for information is at [the rsyslog documentation for property replacer](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/property_replacer.html). If the list of tags is always the same length, you can use substring. Otherwise you'll need to use a regexp, e.g.

%msg:R:.*(tags:[\S]+).*--end%